# Python sum and organize csv data

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv

This program pretty much takes the data from the Data file, analyzes it (negative numers -> 0) and saves everything to a new file.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def convert(item): 
    try:
        item = float(item)
        if item < 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return item
    except ValueError:
        return item

sums = defaultdict(list)

with open('Data.csv', 'r') as inp, open('output1.csv', 'w', newline = '') as outp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp, delimiter = ';')
    writer = csv.writer(outp, delimiter = ';', dialect = 'excel')
    headers = next(reader)
    for line in reader: 
        line = [convert(i) for i in line]
        sums[line[1]+line[2]+line[3]+line[4]+line[5]+line[6]+line[7]+line[8]
             ].append(line[1])
        writer.writerow(line)

for k,v in sums.items():
    print(line[0], '{} total: {}'.format(k,sum(v)))
```

I want to add all values per day to one row, so it would be something like:

```
1.1.2016 369416  
2.1.2016 4825
```

...etc. to a new (or the existing output) file. (So sum the numbers after analyzing and modifying negatives to 0)
Can it be done straight, or should lists be used to save the values first?
I can't add that "line[0]" in the end, it doesn't print the dates right, only prints the very last date.
The data file can be downloaded: https://files.fm/u/yuf4bbuk
First 10 rows of data https://pastebin.com/9HxwcixZ
Continues from url/53355207

Comment: Can you please copy paste portion of the data file here? Or pastebin

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9HxwcixZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not far, but instead of `sums[line[1]+line[2]+line[3]+line[4]+line[5]+line[6]+line[7]+line[8]].append(line[1])`, you should compute a key based on the first column `line[0]` by extracting the date with a substring:

```
with open('solarData.csv', 'r') as inp, open('output.csv', 'w', newline = '') as outp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp, delimiter = ';')
    headers = next(reader)
    for line in reader: 
        line = [convert(i) for i in line]
        sums[line[0][:10]].append(line[1]+line[2]+line[3]+line[4]+line[5]+line[6]+line[7]+line[8])

    writer = csv.writer(outp, delimiter = ';', dialect = 'excel')
    for k, v in sums.items():
        print('{} : {}'.format(k, sum(v)))
        writer.writerow([k, sum(v)])
```

gives

```
2016-01-01;369416.0
2016-01-02;4825.0
2016-01-03;0.0
```

You could also precompute the sum instead of adding to a list, and also print cumulative values:

```
sums = defaultdict(lambda:0)

with open('solarData.csv', 'r') as inp, open('output2.csv', 'w', newline = '') as outp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp, delimiter = ';')
    headers = next(reader)
    for line in reader: 
        line = [convert(i) for i in line]
        sums[line[0][:10]] += line[1]+line[2]+line[3]+line[4]+line[5]+line[6]+line[7]+line[8]

    writer = csv.writer(outp, delimiter = ';', dialect = 'excel')
    cumulative = 0
    for k, v in sums.items():
        cumulative += v
        print('{} : {}\t{}'.format(k, v, cumulative))
        writer.writerow([k, v, cumulative])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!  
Would it be hard to add Cumulative data too, with keeping the daily values (printing the cumulative right after the daily data)? I tried to work around it, so I'd just add up the numbers of the existing sum, but couldn't manage it.
`1.1.2016;358006
2.1.2016;358045
...
8.1.2016;597188
9.1.2016;679353`

Comment: Yes of course, you can use a cumulative variable as specified in my edit.

Comment: Thanks, one more edit if I can ask, is it possible to first print all the day values and after those it starts from the start to print the cumulative values?